# Formatting issue on close reason list

Tags: bug, status-completed, ios-app

The count of closure votes against a given reason is trying to escape from its safe blue pen:

[image: formatting issue on close reason list]

- App Version: 1.6.0.10
- Device: iPhone 6s
- OS Version: Version 10.0.2 (Build 14A456)

Comment: Do the votes get cancelled if it successfully gets out of the pen?

Comment: @Barmar only if they escape the page completely, otherwise they might end up on the wrong close reason

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Vote counts will be safely trapped in their boxes in 1.6.1.1.

We had the same issue with bounties.  I forgot to fix it here.  We are using TTTAttributedLabel to add the border radius to the background and in iOS 10 it is miscalculating the baseline offset of the text its supposed to put a background on.

To fix this, I'm now rendering the blue box and text as an image and placing it in a NSTextAttachment.  This has the positive side effect of letting me rip out TTTAttributedLabel in a bunch of places.

Comment: Cool, will accept whenever that version drops.