# Vote to close titles missing

Tags: bug, status-completed, vote-to-close, ios-app

The close vote dialog on the iOS app has no titles on the options:

> [image]

Unless there is an existing vote where that specific title shows (including the current vote count indicator):

> [image]

Since it only shows when there is a vote count to display, I'm assuming it is a side effect of [this fix](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/285395/307988).

For reference, this is what it should look like (old image I took from elsewhere, but you get the idea):

> [image]

---

- App Version: 1.6.1.1
- Device: iPhone 6s
- OS Version: Version 10.0.1 (Build 14A403)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This will be fixed in 1.6.1.2.

As you could guess, I was incorrectly returning `nil` if I didn't need to append a vote count, rather than just returning the unmodified title.

Comment: Thanks Brian, it's actually a lot harder to use without titles than I thought it would be, look forward to getting them back! :)

Comment: They're back! (can confirm they work, with and without existing vote count indicator)